# file_get_contents or cURL not giving any output

Tags: php

im trying  to get the content of url: https://allegro.pl

I've tried file_get_contents and cURL and i get empty output for that specific domain. With any other websites it works fine...

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://allegro.pl/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)');
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $output;
```

Comment: I'm not clicking on this random URL - is it a real URL?  Does it load from the browser?

Comment: Yes, it is real URL and it loads from a browser. Its a huge website similar to ebay.

Comment: Probably because they don't want you scraping it.

Comment: I tested your code in http://phpfiddle.org and worked.

Comment: Oh! i see it works on phpfiddle.org - but what can be the reason that i cant run it on my server...

Comment: Check content of `$output` using `var_dump()`. Also check response header. Maybe site blocked your server's ip

Answer (score 2):

This site doesn't allow to be called by a script. In it's response header it states:

```
$ curl -I https://allegro.pl
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
…
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
```

`nosniff` is explained here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Content-Type-Options#Syntax